# ServiceStack OrmLite with Ms Access Database First Approach

Tags: c#, ms-access, servicestack, ormlite, ormlite-servicestack

I am relatively new to servicestack. I have searched enough but couldn't find any answer. I have worked with sql database first approach with t4 templates which worked fine. But my scenario has been changed and now i have to work with Ms Access database. I tried to generate POCO with ORMLite but it didn't work.

So my question is Do ORMLite work with MS Access Database.

Or any other ORM which works with service stack to generate models/classes from database.

Comment: Please don't base a webservice on MS Access. Convince your customer, that it's a bad idea.

Comment: Use SQLite if you want a file database, MS Access shouldn't be used in servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ServiceStack Github page these flavours of databases are supported:

- ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer
- ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL
- ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite
- ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle (unofficial)
- ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird (unofficial)
- ServiceStack.OrmLite.VistaDb (unofficial)

So the answer must be: No, MSAccess is not supported.

Regarding other ORM's, Dapper supports anything that has ADO.Net support, but to generate POCO's you need something that is not database-agnostic.

Comment: how can i generate POCO if i use Dapper?

Comment: @Farhan Ali: I don't think any projects support it directly. Dapper.SimpleCrud has a T4 template, that you could modify to work with Access: https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/wiki/T4-Template. But there is a reason why Access is rarely supported: It's simply not the right tool for the job.